# How to get the position of a JavaScript regexp sub-match?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is a simplified version of my RegEx:

```
re = /a(.*)b(.*)c(.*)d/;
match = re.exec("axbxcxd");
```

As expected, this results in `match[1]`, `match[2]` and `match[3]` being `"x"`, but I need to get the position of the middle match number 2. In Python, I can just use `match.position(2)`. Is there any equivalent way in JavaScript to get the position of a sub-match?  I can't just search for the matched string because some of the other sub-matches may be the same.

Comment: just use `match[2]`?

Comment: @raser that gives you the *text* of the second match group, not the position

Comment: Search for functions within the match object ? match[2].position ?

Comment: Dont think this is doable, have had a good look around. Read this: https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2012-July/024066.html

Comment: Please have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: could you please tell me the way you do that in python? as `AttributeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object has no attribute 'position'`

Comment: @DRC: it's `start`, `end` and `span`, not "position".

Comment: @georg I was referring to the OP question, citing match.position(2)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't have an integrated API (yet) to return the positions of sub-matches.

There was some [discussion on the ECMAScript mailing list](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2012-July/024063.html) about adding such an API, though without result so far.

There are already a few tools like [regexplained](http://leaverou.github.io/regexplained/) and the [HiFi Regex Tester](http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex). Though they fail to determine the positions of the sub-matches in cases like `/aa(a)/` matching the string `"aaa"`.

What these tools do is to search the sub-matches within the main match returned by `regexp.exec()` using `string.indexOf()`. Here's some example code:

```
var string = "xxxabcxxx";
var regexp = /a(b(c))/g;

var matches = regexp.exec(string);
if (matches) {
  matches[0] = {
    text: matches[0],
    pos: regexp.lastIndex - matches[0].length
  };

  for(var i = 1; i < matches.length; i++) {
    matches[i] = {
      text: matches[i],
      pos: string.indexOf(matches[i], matches[0].pos)
    };
  }
}

console.log(matches);
```

This outputs an array of match objects containing the positions of the sub-matches:

```
  [
    {
      text: "abc",
      pos: 3
    },
    {
      text: "bc",
      pos: 3
    },
    {
      text: "c",
      pos: 5
    }
  ]
```

*Though note again that the code above, like the mentioned tools, does not work for all cases.*

Answer (score -2):

The `match` object has something called as `index`, I think that is what you're looking for:

`["axbxcxd", "x", "x", "x", index: 0, input: "axbxcxd"]`

---

**EDIT**

Ok. I think I didn't get the question properly the first time around. Here's the updated answer:

```
re = /a(.*)b(.*)c(.*)d/;
str = "axbxcxd";
match = re.exec(str);
searchStr = match[1]; //can be either match[2],match[3]
searchStrLen = match[1].length; //can be either match[2],match[3]
var index, indices = []
var startIndex = 0;
while ((index = str.indexOf(searchStr, startIndex)) > -1) {
        indices.push(index);
        startIndex = index + searchStrLen;
}
console.log(indices[1]); // index of match[2]
console.log(indices[0]); // index of match[1]
console.log(indices[2]); // index of match[3] .. and so on, because some people don't get it with a single example
```

This is a probably a hack, but should work.
A working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8dkLq8m0/

Comment: @Jamiec ah. Makes sense. But given the example in OP's question, the code above should work.

Comment: Deleted comment. Great.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my original comment because I didnt want to be a smartass without backing up my argumnet. Your edit just doesnt work except for the very limited (and contrived) example. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/oopf80wp/ same pattern, valid input but your code doesnt work.

Comment: It does, instead of doing a console.log(indices[1]), just do a console.log(indices[0]), since there is just a single match for your input string.

Comment: No, I want the index of the second match group, or the third. That was the question!

Comment: @Jamiec well, you have the array of indices for all matches, choose whichever one you want. But I see no point trying to make you understand, because you just won't. Your counterexample just has a single match, how can I give you the index of the second or third match group.